# LibreOffice Command Line Conversion - No Output File?

Tags: linux, pdf, powerpoint, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice installed on my Linux box and I seem to be having a weird problem in that the conversion seems to be taking place, and there seem to be no errors, but there is no output file in the specified output directory.

Here is an example of the command I am using:

```
/opt/libreoffice3.6/program/soffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf /dir/file.pptx --outdir /dir
```

And here is the result of that command:

```
convert /dir/file.pptx -> /dir/file.pdf using impress_pdf_Export
```

But the problem is that after running the conversion /dir/file.pdf does not exist.

Do any of you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant reproduce your error. It works for me, even with pptx files.

Check the bug-tracker of libreoffice. Try another version (I am still running 3.4.something). Investigate the output directory - e.g. do you have write privileges there?

And a rather stupid idea: Hit F5 (or similar) in your file browser (mine is Dolphin) in order to refresh. I needed to do this in this case, so I could see the new file.

Comment: I am running this on my Linux server, so I do not have GUI capabilities. The file permissions on my directory are 755, as they should be. I have version 3.6.3 installed, but I am upgrading to 3.6.4 right now, so I will see if that changes anything.

Comment: Alright, so I upgraded to 3.6.4, and that did not change anything. The output file still does not seem to exist even though the conversion is taking place. Any ideas?

Comment: Alright, here is the problem. It seems pptx files are not working, as I just tried a doc file and the command worked, and saved properly. Even though the conversion seems to be taking place with the pptx file, it does not seem to save it anywhere, oddly.

Answer (score 5):

If you see no output then the problem may be related to [this bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37531). Just make sure that there is no other instance of libre office running (soffice.bin). [Source](http://en.libreofficeforum.org/node/2912).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where soffice seemed to run fine (headless mode on server) but there were no output files.

Fixed it by running `apt-get install libreoffice-writer`

Answer (score 1):

Go to the folder your file is in & convert it to that location to see if your conversion works.
If it works, try to put "" around your file to convert.

I have a bashscript that you can maybe use for your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

# first do chmod +x convert.sh
# then run ./convert.sh

mkdir out
cd testfiles
for file in *; do
    echo "${file}"
    soffice --headless -convert-to pdf:"writer_pdf_Export"      
        --outdir ../Documenten/BLACK/out "${file}" 
done
cd ..
```

Comment: sorry for the output of the text but im new here :)