# Linux LibreOfice Headless Conversion no Output?

Tags: linux, pdf, redhat, libreoffice

I am trying to convert a .docx file to PDF using LibreOffice 4.3 on RHEL 6.5 (corporate server).
For some reason, there is no output at all:

```
../program/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir . lock.docx
```

I am running the command as root, so I don't see any problems with permissions.

[This is similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734542/libreoffice-command-line-conversion-no-output-file), but I cannot convert ANY MS Office documents.
I installed LO on an EC2 instance, and it converts .docx to PDF just fine.

What areas could be causing the issue? Any suggestions on what I should be looking at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed a whole set of dependent RPMs installed first, culminating in libGLU. I've included my additional RPM dependency tree if it will be of use:

```
            libIDL-0.8.13-2.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
        ORBit2-2.14.17-5.el6.x86_64.rpm
        sgml-common-0.6.3-33.el6.noarch.rpm
        GConf2-2.28.0-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
    avahi-glib-0.6.25-15.el6.x86_64.rpm
gnome-vfs2-2.24.2-6.el6.x86_64.rpm

                    libXxf86vm-1.1.2-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
                mesa-dri-filesystem-9.2-0.5.el6_5.2.x86_64.rpm
            mesa-private-llvm-3.3-0.3.rc3.el6.x86_64.rpm
            mesa-dri1-drivers-7.11-8.el6.x86_64.rpm (--nodeps)
        mesa-dri-drivers-9.2-0.5.el6_5.2.x86_64.rpm
    mesa-libGL-9.2-0.5.el6_5.2.x86_64.rpm
mesa-libGLU-9.2-0.5.el6_5.2.x86_64.rpm
```