# How can I convert a .ods file to an .xls file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I need to convert a OpenDocument spreadsheet (`.ods`) to an Excel compatible-file (`.xls` or `.xlsx`)

I know it's possible [using `libreoffice` cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734542/libreoffice-command-line-conversion-no-output-file). I would like to do this exact thing using Java. I know that Java could run the command-line process but I would prefer a JVM-only solution (not requiring libreoffice on the environment). Is there any open-source library that could help?

Comment: Your question is better suited for a place like http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The xlsx is like ods a zip format with internally XML, image files and such. So a conversion is not too hard. Also MS Word can handle .ods, though maybe not out-of-the-box.

Comment: @JoopEggen yes, exactly, so I guess someone, somewhere already made a library or something, I can't be the only-one!

Comment: How much fidelity do you need in the conversion? Just values and formulas? Or everything with images, formatting, graphs etc?

Comment: @Gagravarr values + formatting would be enough AFAIK

Comment: I see your `apache-poi` tag, but POI does not read or write `.ods` files.

Comment: Tika can read ods, you might need to convert to an intermediate state perhaps xhtml, and then it should be easy to use poi to push that content in. Tika isn't perfect it might drop formatting.

Comment: You could use [Apache ODFToolkit (incubating)](https://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/) to read the ODS file in, then Apache POI to write it out. Probably a couple of hundred lines of code tops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up by calling libreoffice.

```
File outputDirectory = source.getParentFile();
String[] command = {
        "/usr/bin/libreoffice",
        "--headless",
        "--invisible",
        "-env:UserInstallation=file://" + SystemUtils.getJavaIoTmpDir().getAbsolutePath(), // prevent conversion to fail or just do nothing if libreoffice is already running
        "--convert-to",
        "ods",
        "--outdir",
        outputDirectory,
        source.getAbsolutePath()
};
try {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    processBuilder.directory(outputDirectory);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    int returnValue = process.waitFor();
    if (returnValue == 0) {
        log.debug("process ended successfully");
    } else {
        log.error("process ended with error code " + returnValue);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new UncheckedIOException("cannot convert " + source, e);
}
```